# R: grep multiple patterns and switch result?

Tags: r, regex, vector

Say, I have a vector name "str", which contain many strings like

```
"Houston is a good city."

"I went to San Diego."
...
```

And, I have a data frame named 'States':

```
'City','State'
'Houston','TX'
'San Antonio','TX'
'San Diego','CA'
'Phoenix',"AZ"
......
```

Now I want to generate an extra column names "State" for "str". I want to use the city name as pattern to "grep" the str vector, if match "houston" then put "TX" in the new column, if match Phoenix then put AZ, and so on. Finally I want to get a data frame like this:

```
"Houston is a good city." "TX"
"I went to San Diego." "CA"
......
```

What's the best way to do this, without using sapply or for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, construct pattern string of state names

```
> pattern = "(Houston)|(San Antonio)|(San Diego)|(Phoenix)"
```

Then, use `stringr::str_extract_all` or `stringr::str_extract` to extract state names from string  and add new column to data frame.

```
> stringr::str_extract("Houston is a good city.","(Houston)|(San Antonio)|(San Diego)|(Phoenix)")
[1] "Houston"
```

Then merge earlier data frames to obtain suitable data frame.

Comment: Thanks. Can I use a vector as the first argument for 'str_extract' ?

Comment: @user1451586, Yes, you can.

Answer (score 0):

Since you work with `data.frame`s, using `dplyr` could be a good solution for you:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

str <- data.frame(str=c("Houston is a good city.",
                          "I went to San Diego."),stringsAsFactors = F)

states <- data.frame(City = c('Houston','San Antonio','San Diego','Phoenix'),
                    State = c('TX','TX','CA','AZ'),stringsAsFactors = F)


str <- str %>% mutate(state = states$State[match(str_extract_all(pattern = paste0(states$City,collapse = '|'),
                                              string = .,simplify = T),states$City)])
```

This gives me

```
> str
                      str state
1 Houston is a good city.    TX
2    I went to San Diego.    CA
```

The approach is to use `mutate` to create a new column, where I extract the city with `str_extract_all` and then `match` it to the cities in `states` to index the corresponding state.

This will only work if there's exactly one city match per string.

Comment: It seems to be a good solution. Can you explain more about "%>%"?

Comment: `%>%` is the pipe operator from the `magrittr`package. You can use it to chain together multiple functions where `%>%` passes on the returned result form the function on the left hand side to the right one. You can read more in detail about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/652/pipe-operators-and-others#t=201708012155442835299) and [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr)

Comment: Actually, Mahdi's answer solved my problem, also solved your problem. If you use str_extract instead of str_extract_all, then even if there're two or more cities in a single string, it can just extract the first one. But still thank you for the answer. Learned a lot from the dplyr package.

Comment: That is of course if per default the first city should determine the state. But I agree, it solves the problem. Since @Mahdi 's answer solved your problem, you should accept it

Answer (score 0):

Although the previous answers work great, here is another solution not relying on external packages:

```
str <- c("Houston is a good city.", "I went to San Diego.")

States <- data.frame(City = c('Houston','San Antonio','San Diego','Phoenix'),
                     State = c('TX','TX','CA','AZ'), 
                     stringsAsFactors = F)


match <-  sapply(States$City, function(x) grepl(x, str))
dimnames(match)[[2]] <- unique(States$City)

st <- apply(match, 1, FUN = function(x) States$State[States$City %in% names(x[which(x)])])

new <-  data.frame(str = str, state = st)
```

which gives:

```
>                       str state
> 1 Houston is a good city.    TX
> 2    I went to San Diego.    CA
```

Comment: I don't really like the apply family. To me, they look more like a loop actually, which doesn't match R's spirit of 'vector'.